# python pandas reshape data from long to wide

Tags: python, pandas, analytics, reshape, data-transform

I have a dataframe in the following format that I am trying to reshape into wide format in pandas.

But I am getting the error Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape.

`df`:

| id | status | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | item_ordered | complete |
| 1 | item_received | complete |
| 1 | item_setup | complete |
| 2 | item_ordered | complete |
| 2 | item_setup | complete |
| 2 | item_setup |  |

The format that I am trying to reshape to:

| id | item_ordered | item_received | item_setup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | complete | complete | complete |
| 2 | complete | complete |  |

Comment: the second last row should be 'item_received' per the expected result

Comment: provided data and expected result don't match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the dataframe by `id` and `status` columns, then take the first values for `value` column, finally `unstack` the resulting series:

```py
>>> df.groupby(['id', 'status']).value.first().unstack().reset_index()

status  id item_ordered item_received item_setup
0        1     complete      complete   complete
1        2     complete           NaN   complete
```

Comment: The id column seems to be missing from the final df

Comment: @Datamaniac just add `reset_index()` at last

Comment: Look at the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df.dropna().pivot(index='id', columns='status', values='value')
```

```py
status item_ordered item_received item_setup
id                                          
1          complete      complete   complete
2          complete           NaN   complete
```

The reason of an error is that for `id == 2`, the column `status` contains two indentical values (which will be used for the column index): `item_setup`.

Comment: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape - I get the same error using this code

Comment: @Datamaniac All your `status` values must be unique for each `id`. I haven't seen your full data - so I cannot tell you how you want to transform your data to reach this requirement ... For example, take first, last, average, etc. In my answer I have assumed that removing all nans would be sufficient (based on your example in the question)

Answer (score 0):

the second last row should be 'item_received' per the expected result

```
df.fillna('').pivot(index='id', columns='status')
```

```
    value
status  item_ordered    item_received   item_setup
id          
1           complete         complete   complete
2           complete         complete
```

if there are multiple statuses per id

```
df.pivot (index=['id','id2'], columns='status').fillna('').droplevel(1)
```

```
    id  value
status      item_ordered    item_received   item_setup
0   1           complete         complete     complete
1   2           complete                      complete
2   2
```

data used

````
data={'id': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2},
 'status': {0: 'item_ordered ',
  1: 'item_received ',
  2: 'item_setup ',
  3: 'item_ordered ',
  4: 'item_received ',
  5: 'item_setup '},
 'value': {0: 'complete',
  1: 'complete',
  2: 'complete',
  3: 'complete',
  4: 'complete',
  5: nan}}```
````

Comment: @VladimirFokow, the expected result don't match the provided table. it seems to have a typo